# Image processing in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I have a processed image in GIMP that I would like to copy the edits/history for and then apply those steps to a new image. otherwise, I will have to go through all the processing steps I took before (most of which I can't remember).

I have a bulk set of photos I need to apply that history of edits too. Does anybody know a way of doing it?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Automate_Editing_in_GIMP/

Comment: Thi is one of the worst "tutorials" around. Makes thing more complicated than writing a plain script!

Comment: You can try ImageMagick. See [this link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/) (or browse the internet for 'imagemagick tutorial' (without quotes)).

Answer (score 0):

No such way in Gimp. Many of the raw-processing tools (RawTherapee and others[1]) will:

1. Edit JPEG (despite their name)
2. Save the editing as a receipt/sidecar
3. Have some way to apply the receipts in batch to other files.

Of course, these tools are for "technical" editing (color, contrast, distortion...) and on't have any "artistic" filter.

[1] And IIRC, even Canon's DPP...